# Flexbox and overflow: hidden not working properly

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a bit of HTML:

```css
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
  .flex > div {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: auto;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
    margin: 15px;
  }
    .example {
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100%;
      outline: 5px solid black;
    }
      .example .wide {
        width: 400px;
      }

.red    { background-color: red; }
.orange { background-color: orange; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
.green  { background-color: green; }
.blue   { background-color: blue; }
.indigo { background-color: indigo; }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="red">
    <div class="example">
      <div class="wide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="indigo"></div>
</div>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="orange"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="indigo"></div>
</div>
```

Now, the problem here is, if I have a `div` **inside** an element that is a flexbox and that `div` has `overflow: hidden;` (i.e. `.example`, with the thick black outline) them I would expect the parent flexbox to just take up the default amount of space (i.e. the same as the other elements, but it doesn't.

It is like it ignores the `overflow` and just expands the `div` anyway.

I have made a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/r3plica/pen/dGPmyN?editors=110) so you can see the issue.

I would like all the coloured `div`s to be the same width.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Simply add `min-height: 0;` to the flex child that [has our overflow container](https://moduscreate.com/blog/how-to-fix-overflow-issues-in-css-flex-layouts/).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is caused by setting the `flex-basis` of `.flex > div` to `auto`. This causes the div to expand to accommodate its content as it has no set dimension along the flex axis. Give it a set value like `20px` and the space will be evenly divided because `flex-grow` is set to `1`.

[This article](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) should help you get started with the flex layout.

Here is a [modified version](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeyKWe?editors=110) of your code

```
.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;

  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  /* set value for the flex basis, the two properties above will evenly 
  divide the space. */
  flex-basis: 20px;

  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;

  margin: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.example {
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.example .wide {
  width: 400px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

only set position of parent element

```
<style>
.parent{
    display:flex;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
.child{
    flex-grow:2
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">

    </div>
</div>
```

this work for me